# Какие преимущества своей bitcoin ноды перед бесплатными сервисами с API?

Tags: php, api, bitcoin

Цель - организовать на нескольких проектах поддержку btc платежей. Хотим чтобы комиссия была минимальной при операциях со средствами.

Появился ряд вопросов, которые пока не удается разрешить:

1) чем лучше использование свой ноды, а не API того же blockchain.com (будет ли это быстрее / меньше комиссия / лучше в плане безопасности)

2) если кто-то ломает blockchain.com он сможет со всем кошельков украсть $

3) blockchain.com пишут что использование их API бесплатно - только комиссия майнерам - это так ? (эта комиссия майнерам не больше - чем если бы поднимать свою ноду?)

Comment: Вы хотите принимать или отправлять платежи?

Comment: и то и другое =)

Comment: Я не могу дать развернутый ответ, так как никогда не видел этого апи. 1) смотрите, есть ли возможность указывать комиссию в апи. если нет, то вы всегда можете выставить меньше в bitcoin core 2) да 3) им нет смысла поднимать комиссию выше рыночной, а своровать часть комиссии они не могут, вы можете проверить свою транзакцию и увидеть кому ушли средства

Comment: Вы можете при помощи какой-то библиотеки создать свою транзакцию с любой комиссией и отправить ее через blockchain.com вот здесь: https://www.blockchain.com/ru/btc/pushtx Возможно такая же опция есть в АПИ